# Width doesn't change for the dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to modify a small alert/dialog box function but for some reason the width won't change from 350px ,which was its initial value.

I've tried to set a minWidth as well,I've permutated between the way the attributes where set,I've tried to put the width to 'auto',used different imports..even made setters and getters but nothing worked.

Here is the code

```
function randomAlertFunction(message,title){

 $d=$('<div></div>').dialog({
     modal:true,
     autoOpen:false,
     width:350,
     buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
                  $(this).dialog("close");
     }
}
});

  var title= title;
  $d.html(message);
  $d.dialog("option","title",title);
  $d.dialog('open');
  $d.focus();
}
```

**Edit**

I solved it by cleaning the cache of the browser!

Comment: it doesn't work to change the width..it has no effect on the box

Comment: You have missed closing `quotes` and `brackets` should be: `$d=$('<div></div>').dialog({`

Comment: I've copied the code badly...but that isn't the problem..thank you for the observation

Comment: `$(this).dialog("close";` is still missing a closing `)`. Just a note, use [JSFiddles](http://jsfiddle.net/5aGxK/) **JSHint** option for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are asking for changing the width after initialiasing dialogue.You can change it using:

1) You will need ui.resizable.js and ui.resizable.css for this.

```
$("#dialogBox").dialog('option','width',700);//new width
```

2) without ui.resizable.js and ui.resizable.css

```
 $("#dialogBox").data("width.dialog", 700);
```

or

```
 $("#dialogBox").css("width", 160);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply...I've tried that and the width stays the same when the box appears..:(

Comment: @Stefan:can you create fiddle.